# Is there an error in "take as many as you can along with you"? Should it be "taking" or is it OK?

Tags: exam-questions, error

In the following question, some part of the sentence may have errors. Find out which part of the sentence has an error and select the appropriate option. If a sentence is free from error, select ‘No Error’.

> In an imperfect world with not-so-perfect people and institutions, you have to play (1)/ your role the best you can, take as many as you can along with you, (2)/ with empathy and a bit of loving detachment. (3)/ No error (4)

Correct Answer: 2
Candidate Answer: 4

In this question the sentence I think is kind of authoritative, so **take** is correct in part 2, I guess examiner is assuming **taking**  as correct.

I have to represent the question and convince the examiner to fetch me marks, what do you think, am I right?

Comment: Number 2 might be the correct answer if the words **your role** were placed ahead of (1) and not as part of it.  As it stands, number 2 reads: **.....play with empathy.....** It doesn't figure.

Comment: In an imperfect world with not-so-perfect people and institutions, you have to play your role the best you can, take as many as you can along with you, with empathy and a bit of loving detachment.

Comment: sir, I have mentioned the pure sentence above,  please explain is **take** correct or **taking**, I chose **take** because I think the sentence is authoritative and like a conversation.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little difficult to parse, but I (unfortunately) agree with the examiner that 2. contains an error—assuming that the number is coming after the part of the sentence with the error and not before.

As you pointed out, the problem centres around *take*—which should be *taking*.

To make it clear, I'll give some simplified versions.

> You have to play X, taking Y. [correct]
>   You have to play X, take Y. [incorrect—this is the same form of the original]
>   You have to play X **and** take Y. [correct]
>   You have to play X. Take Y. [correct]
>   You have to play X, take Y, **or** say Z. [correct]

Focusing on the incorrect version, which matches that of the question, the problem can be further seen if it's rearranged.

> Take Y, you have to play X. [incorrect]
>   Taking Y, you have to play X. [correct]

In the incorrect version, the use of the comma has Y provide additional information about how X occurs, but without an *ing* (gerund) verb form.

The verb tense of *take* only works when the comma is used as part of a conjunction (joining several things with *and* or *or*)—or when the sentence is punctuated without a comma.

Comment: @user3169 I said that in my answer . . .